# How can I force close open connections in RethinkDB?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, database-connection, rethinkdb, rethinkdb-ruby

I have problems with my open connections with RethinkDB. If errors occur in my Sinatra back-end app methods, the connection with Rethink is not closed. Therefore the number of open connections slowly increases.

This results in too many open connections, resulting in the error:

```
Error: the RethinkDB database is not available
```

So questions is twofold: First to help me out right now; how can I close the open Rethink connections?
Secondly, how can I avoid the build-up of open connections? Should I open a connection for every call to my back-end, or should I just open a connection with Rethink once when my app is initiated?

Rethink looks promising, but a little help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's a way to do that in RethinkDB right now. I opened a GitHub issue: github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/issues/4873 . One option in the meantime is to use `tcpkill` (or something similar) to terminate the connection.

Answer (score 0):

You can close a connection by calling `.close` on the connection object returned by `connect`.  It should be OK to open one connection per call to your back-end as long as you close those connections when you're done.  (In general RethinkDB can support a lot of open connections at once, unless it's running on a low-resource system or the OS is configured to limit the number of open connections.)

Comment: Problem is that I dont have a connection object anymore when an error is raised. I could probably build this disconnection in the error catcher, but I wonder how I can now close them after the connections are built but never closed without an connection object.

Comment: Thats why you should close the connection as soon as you don't need it anymore, when you still have the connection object.

Comment: So it is impossible to close connections after you don't have the connection object anymore? No admin or server-side solution either?
That would also be an answer...

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do that right now.  I opened a GitHub issue: https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/issues/4873 .  One option if you really need to kill these connections is to use `tcpkill` (or something similar) to terminate the connection from outside both programs.

Comment: Thanks @mlucy. I think that should be the answer. If you post it as an answer I'll mark that as the solution.